# How to detect evalution by IDE debugger

Tags: c#, debugging

I have a class with a property, and I need to intercept debuggind evaluation.

And i don't known how I can do that.

```
class Foo
{
    public bool DebugIsAllow { get; set; } = false;
    public string Value
    {
        get
        {
            if (!DebugIsAllow && IsDebugging()) throw new Exception();
            return "ok";
        }
    }
    public bool IsDebugging()
    {
        return ?????
    }

    public void Main()
    {
        var v = Value;
Breakpoint here !!!
        DebugIsAllow = true;
Breakpoint here !!!
    }
}
```

At the first breakpoint, if I add spy for 'v' and 'Value', I want see in watch window : v="ok" and Value="Exception"

And at second breakpoin, I want see in watch window : v="ok" and Value="ok"

Thank you for your help.

---

Edit :

I try with "System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached" but but debugger is always attached. Not only when IDE class property by watch window.

Comment: We don't know why you need to do that.  Consider using an obfuscator to make somebody's life more difficult.

Comment: If relevant, consider using the `[DebuggerDisplay]` attribute (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x810d419.aspx) to change what is rendered in Visual Studio tool windows, but it is not designed to be used for obfuscation, and it can be easily worked around anyway.

Comment: It's not for obfuscator. In reality this property is attached with cache system and remote call system. And I don't want to the debugger trigger the remote call. But i want allow it to get value in the cache.

The [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerBrowsable] attribut can disable fully the evaluation. But in this case, I can get easily value in cache...

Comment: Finally I think I will use the DebuggerTypeProxy attribute. But it's remains of dirty the hack, because in my case the evaluation is too slow and I will have an error in the IDE If another class uses this property it will not take advantage of this attribute. And will not add this attribut on all class...

Answer (score 0):

Use the `[DebuggerDisplay]` attribute to implement a custom display scheme for use in the debugger. For example, the `Lazy<T>` class uses this to stop debugging causing lazy evaluation to run.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x810d419.aspx

Answer (score -1):

You can use this compiler directive assuming that the DEBUG constant is defined:

```
public bool IsDebugging()
{
#if DEBUG
    return true;
#else
    return false;
#endif
}
```

Comment: No, It's will not work. "DEBUG" constante will only say if it compiled as debug or release . Not if it's normal excecution or IDE debug call...